# Python iLO2 Monitoring

Tags: html, python-2.7, monitoring

The monitor application that I have uses python for the backend instead of perl. So I am trying to rewrite the nagios check check_ilo2_health in python. The issue I am having is how to pass tags to the ilo from the connection connection so I can get the output. Once I get the output I am sure I can parse through to output the data that I need.

I am trying to use urllib/urllib2 but requests should work all the same.

The tags that need to get passed is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LOCFG VERSION="2.21" />
<RIBCL VERSION="2.21">
<LOGIN USER_LOGIN="USERNAME" PASSWORD="PASSWORD">
<SERVER_INFO MODE="read">
<GET_EMBEDDED_HEALTH />
</SERVER_INFO>
</LOGIN>
</RIBCL>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended having to use a third-party python package. This is not ideal but it works for now. I ended up having to use python-hpilo.

Thanks.